# What is Thread-12 error in Grails Project while run the application

Tags: grails, illegalstateexception

Exception in thread "Thread-12" 
Error |
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No file extensions list found for path not being watched
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.run(WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.java:87)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:154)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher.run(GrailsProjectWatcher.java:161)

Comment: Think you are running grails in Dev mode and it is attempting to do a reload of the updated segment.